# Google Analytics Form Tracking Events not working

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics, universal-analytics

We have a form that we're trying to track in Google Analytics. We have the following code executed after form submission:

```
<script language=\"javascript\">_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'ProductForm', 'submit', window.location.href])</script>
```

And here is the general Analytics code we're using globally on the site:

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
ga('create', 'UA-12345678-1', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

However the form events are not tracking in Analytics. Any idea what's wrong with the particular tracking method we're using or do we simply need to upgrade our Analytics version?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

_gaq.push is outdated, you will need update.

Try that code:

```
ga('send', 'event', {'page': window.location.href,'title': 'ProductForm'});
```

You can see more examples [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events)